# jquery get a data-tag and do something with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, custom-data-attribute

i have this structure:

```
<ul>
  <li data-tag="one" class="hovering">something</li>
  <li data-tag="two">something else</li>
  <li data-tag="two">something else</li>
</ul>
```

what i need is storing in a variable the `data-tag` value of the `<li>` that `hasClass("hovering")` -  i want the alert to print "one".

I've been trying all types of different stuff that revolves more or less around this:

```
var theActiveData = function() {
    $('ul li.hovering').attr("data-tag");
}
alert(theActiveData);
```

but i just can't get this to work

Comment: what exactly do you want from it? Your question is not clear

Comment: `var theActiveData = $('ul li.hovering').data('tag');` is what you're looking for, I believe.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy i want the alert to print "one"

Comment: `var theActiveData = function() {
    return $('ul li.hovering').attr("data-tag");
}
alert(theActiveData());`

Comment: Why are you wrapping the variable assignment in an anonymous function call?  `var theActiveData = $('ul li.hovering').data('tag');`

Comment: You missed the `return` inside function.. also you missed the `()` to execute the function inside the alert

Comment: Make sure you are executing this code once the document is ready but putting it in `$(document).ready()`. Perhaps your li's have not been created at the time the code runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot return

```
var theActiveData = function() {
    return $('ul li.hovering').attr("data-tag");
}
alert(theActiveData);
```

Comment: Also the `()` to execute the function inside alert

Answer (score 0):

You must use jquery data() function like this:

```
var theActiveData = function() {
return($('ul li.hovering').data("tag"))
}
alert(theActiveData());
```

Comment: i want the alert to print "one", but not to set the value. thanks anyway :)

Comment: ok I misunderstood your question, I edited my answer for what you need, you was having some wrong sentences in your code, check mine

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function in the alert and set the function to actually return the value.

```
var theActiveData = function() {
    return $('ul li.hovering').attr("data-tag");
}
alert(theActiveData());
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vna8rjmm/)